# Llama-2 7B-hf repeats context of question directly from input prompt, cuts off with newlines

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

**Context:** I am trying to query Llama-2 7B, taken from HuggingFace (meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf). I give it a question and context (I would guess anywhere from 200-1000 tokens), and ask it to answer the question based on the context (context is retrieved from a vectorstore using similarity search). Here are my two problems:

1. The answer ends, and the rest of the tokens until it reaches `max_new_tokens` are all newlines. Or it just doesn't generate any text and the entire response is newlines. Adding a `repetition_penalty` of 1.1 or greater has solved infinite newline generation, but does not get me full answers.
2. For answers that do generate, they are copied word for word from the given context. This remains the same with `repetition_penalty=1.1`, and making the repetition penalty too high makes the answer nonsense.

I have only tried using `temperature=0.4` and `temperature=0.8`, but from what I have done, tuning temperature and `repetition_penalty` both result in either the context being copied or a nonsensical answer.

**Note about the "context":** I am using a document stored in a Chroma vector store, and similarity search retrieves the relevant information before I pass it to Llama.

**Example Problem:**
My query is to summarize a certain Topic X.

```
query = "Summarize Topic X"
```

The retrieved context from the vectorstore has 3 sources that looks something like this (I format the sources in my query to the LLM separated by newlines):

```
context = """When talking about Topic X, Scenario Y is always referred to. This is due to the relation of
Topic X is a broad topic which covers many aspects of life.
No one knows when Topic X became a thing, its origin is unknown even to this day."""
```

Then the response from Llama-2 directly mirrors one piece of context, and includes no information from the others. Furthermore, it produces many newlines after the answer. If the answer is 100 tokens, and max_new_tokens is 150, I have 50 newlines.

```
response = "When talking about Topic X, Scenario Y is always referred to. This is due to the relation of \n\n\n\n"
```

One of my biggest issues is that in addition to copying one piece of context, if the context ends mid-sentence, so does the LLM response.

Is anyone else experiencing anything like this (newline issue or copying part of your input prompt)? Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common issue with pre-trained base models like Llama.

My first thought would be to select a model that has some sort of instruction tuning done to it i.e https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat. Instruction tuning impacts the model's ability to solve tasks reliably, as opposed to the base model, which is often just trained to predict the next token (which is often why the cutoff happens).

The second thing, in my experience, I have seen that has helped is using the same prompt format that was used during training. You can see in [the source code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/blob/main/llama/generation.py#L44) the prompt format used in training and generation by Meta. [Here](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-chat-GPTQ/discussions/5) is a thread about it.

Finally, for repetition, using a [Logits Processor](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/internal/generation_utils#transformers.RepetitionPenaltyLogitsProcessor) at generation-time has been helpful to reduce repetition.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the resources! Using a tuned model helped, I tried TheBloke/Nous-Hermes-Llama2-GPTQ and it solved my problem. They had a more clear prompt format that was used in training there (since it was actually included in the model card unlike with Llama-7B). And this new model still worked great even without the prompt format.

Comment: Even for the original non-chat models, I still don't understand why it would repeats the long context.

Comment: @SaddlePoint Which models are you talking about, I think my point was that chat models are better at not repeating - since the non-chat, base models are trained on a next-word objective, not to field instrucitons.

Comment: @Jamie I'm agree with you. I just can not understand why the original issue the OP facing will happen - the model repeats completely exactly the same context before giving the response.

Answer (score 1):

HuggingFace Transformers `generate` function concatenates the tokens of prompt and model output together. The method then returns the concatenation of prompt + answer. This is done in this line of code:

**https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/021887682224daf29264f98c759a45e88c82e244/src/transformers/generation/utils.py#L2487**

To address this issue, you need a way to separate prompt tokens from model output tokens. Well, luckly it is easy to do that :)

I suggest encoding the prompt using Llama tokenizer beforehand, so that you can find the length of the prompt token ids. After that, you will be able to splice them out of the `generate` output:

```py
prompt = "Who was the third president of the United States?"
prompt_tokens = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt")["input_ids"]
start_index = prompt_tokens.shape[-1]

output = model.generate(prompt_tokens, num_return_sequences=1)

generation_output = output[0][start_index:]
generation_text = self.tokenizer.decode(generation_output, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This link might help https://replicate.com/blog/how-to-prompt-llama

It says if you use LLaMA-2 specifically, you should wrap the `{question}` like

```
[INST]{question}[/INST]
```

In my code I have

```py
MODEL_ID = "TheBloke/Llama-2-7b-Chat-GPTQ"

TEMPLATE = """
You are a nice and helpful member from the XYZ team who makes product A, B, C and D.
Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.

{context}

[INST]{question}[/INST]"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [chat model](https://huggingface.co/NousResearch/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf) and this model is trained with instruction dataset

Answer (score -1):

It is difficult to answer this with code missing, but here it goes. If you are using Huggingface pipeline for inference, then set `return_full_text=False` to only get generated text (and not the input + generated text).